# stopping RaspPi / raspbmc from auto changing source on tv

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi

My Pi is connected to my TVs usb port which works great and I use the TV remote to control it - which I also enjoy.

The problem is whenever I turn on my TV, the pi changes the TV input source even though I don't want it to.

Is there a way to keep hcmi-cec enabled without it automatically controlling the source on the TV?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain further?
You're powering your pi through the TV's usb port?
Which source is being changed - the video?

Comment: The Pi is physically changing the source on my tv to display the output of the Pi on my tv.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? (Prevent XBMC from starting your TV via HDMI on (re-)start)

Answer (score 6):

You can try adding `hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1` config option to your `/boot/config.txt`. It should, in theory, disable sending initial active source message by RaspberryPi which is probably responsible for changing input source to HDMI in your case.

Comment: thanks Krzysztof that worked great for the Pi itself, now xbmc seems to be changing the hdmi source as well. is there a way to turn it off from within xbmc?

Comment: I don't use XBMC so I can't test it but there should be an option in XBMC settings to disable this. It should be called `Power on TV when starting XBMC` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Krzystof 's excellent answer, I would quote what I read in [this post](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=3001&pid=73382#pid73382):

> Include the `hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1` switch in `/boot/config.txt`.

Then in Settings>System>Input devices>Peripherals>CEC turn off the option: "Make XBMC the active source at start".

Comment: I had to mount `/boot` as `rw` in order to do, similar to http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Config.txt#Editing_config.txt